# How to get rid of "Consider replacing your battery" warning in Windows 7 power settings

Tags: windows-7, battery, battery-life

When I turned on my laptop (Acer Aspire S3-951) today, I saw the following message under the power icon.

[image]

I know that my battery is 61% degraded, but how do I get rid of the extra text that says my battery needs replacement? Is there a way to do this without replacing or removing the power settings/status icon?

Comment: Have you considered replacing your battery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Install Windows Service Pack 1 - it will give you a check (in the area you provided a screenshot of) to turn off notifications.

2) If you don't want to do that, you can do this optional fix:

(This will completely remove your battery icon)

Right click the battery icon, select turn system icons on or off, select Customize notification icons,
Uncheck "Always show all icons and notification on the taskbar:
Choose Power and then select Hide Icon and notifications

Hope that works!

Comment: could you give me a link to Windows Service Pack 1

Comment: Go through this page: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-windows-7-service-pack-1 - follow the steps and you'll be good!

Comment: This is the accepted answer? :)))